# ios- two singleton class with same name 'sharedObj'

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton

I added two singleton classes 'A' and 'B'.

A has object string a1;

```
 A *sharedObject;
    +(A*)getSharedObject{
    if(sharedObject == nil)
    {
    sharedObject = [[A alloc]init];
sharedObject.a1 = @"A obj";
    }
    return sharedObject;
    }
```

B has object string b1;

```
    B *sharedObject;
    +(B*)getSharedObject{
    if(sharedObject == nil)
    {
    sharedObject = [[B alloc]init];
sharedObject.b1 = @"B obj";
    }
    return sharedObject;
    }
```

I used

```
A *aObj = [A getSharedObject];
NSLog(@"%@",aObj.a1);
B *bObj = [B getSharedObject];
NSLog(@"%@",bObj.b1);
```

It crashes saying bObj is of type 'A' and has no object b1. 
Then I gave different names `sharedObectA` and `sharedObjectB`.

I need to know why this happened. Both objects had same name but were class level.

Thanks.

Comment: What was the scope of `sharedObject` within each class?  It sounds like you declared it as a global

Comment: I declared it class A and class B separately. Before implementation. So it should be class level. Or does this objects are global?

Comment: This is the canonical singleton implementation - http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/ - note that the shared instance should be a static variable inside the class method.

Answer (score 0):

Your shared instance variables must be declared as static in the implementation files.

```
static A* sharedObject;
@implementation
+(A*)getSharedObject
{
  if(!sharedObject)
  {
    sharedObject=[[A alloc] init];
  }
  return sharedObject;
} 
//...
@end
```

To create shared instances more safely use dispatch_once snippet.

Answer (score 0):

If you have added all this code in a simple implementation file (.m), you are not declaring and A class methods or and B class methods. you are declaring a methods of the class in the implementation statement: In your class look this: @implementation ThisIsYourClass. 
A ThisIsYourClass clas methods, and both are the same.
In objective C methods are selector (internal and external), in your case both are the same selector,
@selector(getSharedObject). In fact you should have a big warning with duplicate methods. 
When in runtime this selector is called, is always the first.

Comment: No. There are separate classes A and B. No duplication error.